# Cannot access "buffer.Buffer" in client code (Svelte with Userbase)

Tags: typescript, svelte, sveltekit, svelte-3

I'm writing an application using Svelte 3.44 and SvelteKit.
I want to use Userbase (https://userbase.com/) for user authentication and data storage.

I have a component *Login.svelte* in which I want to call Userbase API for signing up and logging in. The relevant code is:

```
<script lang="ts">
    import userbase from 'userbase-js';
    /* Irrelevant code here */
</script>
```

When I try to run this using `vite dev`, then instead of my Login component I see:

```
500

Module "buffer" has been externalized for browser compatibility. Cannot access "buffer.Buffer" in client code.

get@http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/userbase-js.js?v=b25ad0c3:151:17
node_modules/safe-buffer/index.js@http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/userbase-js.js?v=b25ad0c3:162:19
__require@http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-TWLJ45QX.js?v=b25ad0c3:8:50
node_modules/randombytes/browser.js@http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/userbase-js.js?v=b25ad0c3:225:19
__require@http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-TWLJ45QX.js?v=b25ad0c3:8:50
node_modules/diffie-hellman/lib/generatePrime.js@http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/userbase-js.js?v=b25ad0c3:3272:23
__require@http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-TWLJ45QX.js?v=b25ad0c3:8:50
node_modules/diffie-hellman/browser.js@http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/userbase-js.js?v=b25ad0c3:3554:25
__require@http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-TWLJ45QX.js?v=b25ad0c3:8:50
@http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/userbase-js.js?v=b25ad0c3:6166:37
```

Browsing for solutions I found two and none worked:

1. Using dynamic import with OnMount() seems to work, but I can't use the imported module anywhere else outside of OnMount() because of TypeScript type checking.
2. Adding Userbase SDK from index.html and calling it with `window.userbase` didn't work, because I got `ReferenceError: window is not defined`. If I only use it inside OnMount(), then I'm back with problem number one.

To sum up:
If anyone has overcome the `Cannot access "buffer.Buffer" in client code` problem, please tell me how you did that.
Excuse me if this is a stupid question, I'm an embedded developer, this is one of my first encounters with Web Development.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've had the exact same issue and I've been able to solve it!

1. Install `buffer` package, as correctly suggested by [@H.B.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/546730/h-b): `$ npm i buffer`
2. Add this snippet to your `index.html`:

```html
<script>
/**
 * this is a hack for error: global is not defined
 */
var global = global || window
</script>
```

Got this little gem from [this GitHub comment](https://github.com/bevacqua/dragula/issues/602#issuecomment-1109840139)

My component logic so far is:

```
<script>
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';
    import userbase from 'userbase-js';

    onMount(() => {
        userbase.init({ appId: '...' })
    });
</script>
```

Versions:

```
        "@sveltejs/kit": "next"
        "svelte": "^3.44.0",
        "typescript": "^4.7.4",
        "vite": "^3.0.4"
```

Comment: I just tested it and it works! Thank you. I wound up using a different architecture (my own server instead of Userbase) but hopefully this will help somebody else in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce this exact issue, maybe you are using a different version of Vite. You could try to prevent `buffer` from being externalized by adding it to [`ssr.noExternal`](https://vitejs.dev/config/ssr-options.html#ssr-noexternal).

I get a different error which also suggests that the module should be imported  only in the browser.

Accessing something outside of `onMount` is only a typing or scoping issue. If you import it in a component you can declare a variable outside of `onMount`. It will be undefined until the import has completed:

```html
<script lang="ts">
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';
    import type { Userbase } from 'userbase-js';

    let userbase: Userbase | undefined;

    onMount(async () => {
        window.global = window; // If you get a "global is not defined error"
        userbase = await import('userbase-js').then(x => x.default);
    });
</script>
```

If you import the script elsewhere globally, you should be able to access `window.userbase`, the type declaration files of the module already define this :

```js
// Expose as userbase when loaded in an IIFE environment
export as namespace userbase
```

Comment: I added `ssr: { noExternal: true,}` in `vite.config.js` to prevent anything from being externalized and used your code snippet, first importing type and then inside `onMount()` importing the userbase object. There is some progress - I can see my Login component now. Unfortunately, when I open the browser console I still see `Uncaught (in promise) Error: Module "buffer" has been externalized for browser compatibility. Cannot access "buffer.Buffer" in client code.` and I can see that the userbase variable is still undefined.

Comment: As I do not get the buffer error at all, I unfortunately cannot help with that

Answer (score 0):

This idea may help:
[Module "util" has been externalized for browser compatibility. Cannot access "util.promisify" in client code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73335430/module-util-has-been-externalized-for-browser-compatibility-cannot-access-ut)
Something like this:

```js
export default defineConfig({
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      util: 'util/',
    },
  },
})
```

Comment: Indeed, this pointed me out in the right direction. First installed buffer module `npm i buffer` then added the alias in `vite.config.ts` as described (replace `util` by `buffer`) above ! But this still lacks some explanation on why this problem occurs and why we need an alias ?